# Calling method of Fragment has no effect

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

And first of all thank you anyway for your help.
This is a difficult question for me.

Please I have an activity that contains 5 Fragments; on user interaction the Fragments get swapped.

I am using the ACL.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        stackArray =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        favQ =new ArrayList<Stock>();
        tablet=true;
        mBound = false;
        fragmentActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.splashmain);
        splashfragment =new splashFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.splashview,splashfragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        /*
            other stuff....
            */
        fragmentlista = new listafragment();
        fragmentfavourites= new favouritesFragment() ;
        worstbest = new WorstBest();
        searchfragment = new searchFragment(); 
        /*
            other stuff....
            */
        lt = mService.ritira();
        worst=mService.ritiraWorst();
        best=mService.ritiraBest();
        favQ.clear();
        favQ.addAll(mService.ritiraFav());          
            fragmentlista.prendiLista(lt);
        worstbest.prendiListaWorst(worst);
        worstbest.prendiListaBest(best);
        if(favQ.size()>0)fragmentfavourites.prendiLista(favQ);

// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() WORKS!!! <---
// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() WORKS!!! <---

            splashfragment.enableAll();

// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() WORKS!!! <---
// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() WORKS!!! <---
        /*
            other stuff....
            */
        }

//Method invoked to setup the configuration of the screen is layoutSchermo(int conf)
public static void layoutSchermo(int conf){
//Check if it is a Tablet in Landscape mode or not
//if it finds v2 than we are on a LARGE screen, then we check ORIENTATIO
    fragmentActivity.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View v2 =(View)fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.view2);
    if(v2==null 
            & 
            fragmentActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        tablet=false;

//Calls the screen configuration LIST
if(conf==LIST){     
    fragmentActivity.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.remove(splashfragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    //Remove old Fragment splashfragment
//At this point I expect the fragment splashfragment is destroyed
//OR NOT???
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    if(!tablet){fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view1, fragmentlista);}
    if(tablet){
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view1, splashfragment);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view2,fragmentlista );
        }       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);   
    stack= fragmentTransaction.commit();
    stackArray.add(stack);
//Brand new fragments added


// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() NOT WORKING!!! <---
// --->>>>HERE THE SAME METHOD enableAll() NOT WORKING!!! <---

splashfragment.enableAll(); 
    }
```

### ------------

So basically what happens and where the problem is:

**The problem is in the method**

```
layoutSchermo(int conf)
```

In the method layoutSchermo(int conf),

I detach a Fragment (splashfragment) and reattach it (together with another one).

It is not clear to me if when I call

```
 remove(splashfragment)
```

**Actually the Fragment is destroyed or not?**

Additionally, whenever the Fragment freshly added is a new one or the old one,
why the call to

```
splashfragment.enableAll();
```

Has no effect ?

**I expect it to work either it is the new or old Fragment!**

Please enlighten me!

Thanks
maurizio

### ----------

*EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT* 
*Here is the code of the fragment (I do not think it helps much)*

```
ublic class splashFragment extends Fragment {
    public View v;
    public Button buttonfav;
    public Button buttonBW;
    public Button buttonSe;
    public Button buttonLi;


    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.splashnew, container, false);
        RelativeLayout box1 = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.box1);
        //box1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        buttonfav=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.heart);
        buttonBW=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.star);
    buttonSe=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.search);
        buttonLi=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lista);

        buttonfav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hearth_gray_tansp);
        buttonBW.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_gray_trans);
        buttonSe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_gray_transp);
        buttonLi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_gray_trans);

        buttonfav.setEnabled(false);
        buttonBW.setEnabled(false);
    buttonSe.setEnabled(false);
        buttonLi.setEnabled(false);

        buttonfav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Quotes.layoutSchermo(Quotes.FAVOURITES);
            }});

        buttonBW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Quotes.layoutSchermo(Quotes.BESTWORST);
            }});

        buttonSe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Quotes.layoutSchermo(Quotes.SEARCH);
            }});

        buttonLi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Quotes.layoutSchermo(Quotes.LIST);
            }});
        return v;           
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  } 


public void enableAll(){
    buttonfav.setEnabled(true);
    buttonfav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hearth);
    buttonBW.setEnabled(true);
    buttonBW.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
    buttonLi.setEnabled(true);
    buttonLi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list);
    buttonSe.setEnabled(true);
    buttonSe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exactly fragments are destroyed can't be known with any certainty. All you know is that it's called after onStop() and before onDetach().

As for your splashFragment.enableAll(), you haven't showed us what that method is so how can we know why it isn't working... Also, you haven't showed us the more general context of this layoutSchermo method. I say this because I suspect you're doing this all wrong. You have a static method, referencing activities somehow...(not clear how that's happening), setting the contentview on that activity reference..the whole thing just sets off some red flags.

SplashFragment.enableAll is most likely something that needs to be called inside of that Fragment's onAttach or onResume, but again it's impossible to know without some explanation from you.

EDIT

Ok, so I think you're going about this incorrectly. What you are effectively trying to accomplish is to "configure" your Fragment in a certain way (depending on some state) when you display it again. The issue here is that you don't know exactly when the View hierarchy of a Fragment is inflated or when exactly it's attached to the Activity, etc. In other words, trying to call methods that affect the UI of your fragment simply on the basis of having a reference to the **object** of a Fragment is a mistake. You need to hook into the lifecycle of your Fragment and do things "the correct way."

Here's what I recommend: create a static constructor for your Fragment that makes it easy to create the properly configured Fragment that you want. Here's what that might look like:

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

    public static SplashFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment()
        splashFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return splashFragment;
    }

    // or alternatively
    public static SplashFragment newInstance(int favResource, int bwResource, int liResource, int seResource,
        boolean favEnabled, boolean bwEnabled, boolean liEnabled, boolean seEnabled) {
        SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment()
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("fav_res", favResource);
        bundle.putInt("bw_res", bwResource);
        bundle.putInt"li_res", liResource);
        bundle.putInt("se_res", seResource);
        bundle.putBoolean("fav_enabled", favEnabled);
        //...And so on  
        splashFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return splashFragment;
    }

    //Then....

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setup your view as normal...then
        buttonFav.setBackgroundResource(getArguments().getInt("fave_res"));
        //.....etc
    }

}
```

Now if you really need to be able to manipulate a Fragment without creating a new instance, then the only way I can think to do this is to add the fragment with a tag, as in the

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

and

```
add (Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

varieties.

Then, later you can try to ask the fragment manager to find those fragment for you, i.e.

```
SplashFragment splashFragment = (SplashFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("some tag here");
```

Check that it's not null and then call your method on it...

Comment: @LuxoryMode basically enableAll() enables and change the background images of the buttons on the Fragment.

Comment: And how is it that you have a reference to splashfragment inside of the layoutSchermo method? It's a field...obviously. So where is this field initialized? Show the whole class that contains layoutSchermo.